# Exception on graphics2D.drawImage()

Tags: java, graphics2d, drawimage

When I use the code below it throws an exception. But when I add:

```
graphics.drawString("some string", 0, 0);
```

to the render method, everything works I tried to find some info about `drawImage()` if there must be anything to do before drawing but couldn't find. Could you tell me what's going on?

Here is the Game class that creates window

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");

        frame.add(new GamePanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the GamePanel

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    //Fields
    public static int WIDTH = 600;
    public static int HEIGHT = 400;

    private BufferedImage image;// = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private Graphics2D graphics;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;

    public GamePanel(){
        if(thread == null){ thread = new Thread(this); thread.start(); }

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        init();

        while(running){            
            render();
            draw();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        running = true;
        timer = System.nanoTime();

        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        graphics = image.createGraphics();
    }

    private void render() {
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    private void draw(){
        Graphics g = (Graphics) getGraphics();
        if (image != null) g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

Ok, so I am trying to create a simple game using "graphics2d" to understand how it works and I am calling draw() and render() methods in a loop non-stop. And without adding `graphics.drawSting("some string", x, y);` to it throws this exception at line 85 which is `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);`

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at GamePanel.draw(GamePanel.java:85)
        at GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:54)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

So I debugged it and without adding `drawString()` in the `render()` method the `g` in the `draw()` method is null but when I add `drawString()` to the `render()` method it is not null and it draws to the window.

Comment: You should NOT be using `getGraphics()` to do custom painting. We don't know the context of how the code is used. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The compiler doesn't throw exceptions, it just reports errors during compilation. Exceptions happen at runtime (you could get an exception if you ignore a compiler error and start the code anyway if your IDE supports that). For a debugging question on SO, you need to post the exact error message that you received.

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: *Is it more clear now?* - no. You have not posted an "MRE".  You have a NPE. Again, we don't know the context of how each method is invoked. We don't even have any idea what class you are extending. You have a NPE, so which variable is null? We can't tell you that so you need to do your own debugging. Once you know that you can fix the problem.

Comment: Check the value of image before passing into the method `drawImage(image, 0, 0, null)` such exception can be due to **null value of image**

Comment: Your call to method `getGraphics()` in method `draw()` of class `GamePanel` is returning null.

Comment: 1) We can't run that code since the panel isn't displayed in a frame. 2) You still haven't stated which variable is null. If you don't know which variable is null how can you expect to solve the problem?. This is basic debugging that you should be doing before you post a question. If you tell us which variable is null we might be able to tell you why it is null. 3) you should not have a tight loop. Maybe the render() and draw() without having the Thread sleep for a short period is overwhelming the painting.

Comment: There is nothing null everything is defined because it works when I draw a string in render() method which means the image is not null. I also stated that I created a frame in another class and added the GamePanel class to it.

Comment: *There is nothing null* - of course there is something null or you wouldn't get the message. *it works when I draw a string in render() method* - but the statement in error is NOT in the render method, it is in the `draw()` method. Just because you invoke a method to get a graphics object does not mean the will will actually return a Graphics object. Where did you add a `System.out.println(...)` statement to display the value of all your variables used on line 85?

Comment: *I also stated that I created a frame in another class and added the GamePanel class to it* - but you didn't post the code here. We can't copy/paste/compile and test the code you posted. The point of the "MRE" is to provide simple code that we can test.

Comment: Ok so I apologize again and I edited one more time you can read the last paragraph for debugging results.  Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: All that is relevant is the statement causing the problem. I have asked you multiple time, which variable on that statement is null. I have suggested you can use `System.out.println(...)` to print the value of every variable used by that statement. This is basic debugging. Once you tell me which variable is null then we can start to solve the problem. If I give you the answer, you still will not have learned how to solve your next NullPointerException. Also, the posted code does not compile. That is why all the code should be in a single source file that you compile and test before posting.

Comment: The `g` itself is null.

Comment: *The g itself is null.* - Finally. 4 hours later you actually tell us what the problem is.  The problem with your code is you create the Thread in the constructor so the panel immediately tries to do painting, but the getGraphics() method can't return a Graphics object because the panel has not yet been added to a visible frame. So, the solution is to start the Thread AFTER the panel has been added to the frame and the frame is visible.

Answer (score -1):

what kind of Exception are you getting?
For Drawing an image see this link here.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html
try this:

```
private void draw(){
    Graphics g = (Graphics) getGraphics();
    if (image != null)
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This exception is caused by passing a null image to the drawImage method

Comment: I found a similar answer and tried controlling if the image is null or not but didn't work.